# Swift 3 table header resize if image is not available?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Hello i need one small help

actually the photos explain what i want.

The problem is in my detail of product page can be have an ımage or not.

if ımage is not available ı dont want any space between product title and user photo

if image is available its okay no problem now

[WITH NO PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ0NT.jpg)

[WITH PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWpFm.jpg)

what should i do ? ,  this is table view header

Comment: Set the height of the tableView header according to having a photo or not, with potentially layout constraints.

Comment: if ur using autolayout, then outlet the height of the image view, if there is no image, u can set the height to 0.

Comment: If you have images in array the check according to that and put the condition in the method `heightForRow` accordingly you'll find indexPath in the Args of the method there you'll get the `indexPath.row` and set Accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the information if the header has image in some kind of data source. Then depending on this flag (`hasImage` for instance) you should pass different values for `heightForHeader` of the tableView - one height when you do not have image, and a larger height when you do. Also note that you might need to update your header's view constraints.